# Proofs of trivial zeros of zeta function?

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I know that the trivial zeros of zeta function are negative even integers . I have seen the [wiki-proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Trivial_Zeroes_of_the_Riemann_Zeta_Function)

using the functional equation of zeta function, I might have seen a proof using Bernoulli numbers .

My question :

Do there exist other proofs ?

Comment: The only way to *define* the zeta function for negative numbers is by way of the functional equation, so every proof must use it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ,maybe we can have other proofs by means of analytic continuation .

Comment: The analytic continuation is done by way of the functional equation. That is, it is the functional equation that shows you what the analytic continuation is.

Comment: But see the discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215840/trivial-zeroes-of-the-riemann-zeta-function-are-simple for another point of view.